# Edit value posted back before it gets to the controller in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I would like to amend data before it reaches my controller.

We've altered model binders etc through the solution and so amending those isn't an option for me at this time - I'd like to know however if its possible to amend the value being entered before it hits the controller:

Razor code (inside a `foreach`):

```
@Html.EditorFor(x=>x.Value);
```

I've tried things like `.Replace(...)` but doesn't allow me to amend it that way.

I appreciate what best practice is but time being involved I would like the quick solution and change for the right solution later... Im sure everyone can appreciate that one!

Controller code: (this is why - I need to strip the comma out (which is acceptable in the field, so cant use logic to stop it - I want to replace it with something so I can keep my comma delimited postback)

*(formData is of type FormCollection)*

```
var arrayOfValues = formData["x.Value"].Split(',');
```

So as its a comma delimited value - sometimes that value will be Fred Jones, 1 New Street -> perfectly acceptable entry for what I need, however destroys my comma delimited response.

Any help would be hugely appreciated. This isn't my area of preference at all!

Comment: How are you posting your form? If you use ajax, you can amend it before you submit :)

Comment: @theghostofc I've tried replacing it with replace() (as stated) but wont allow me to do so. I've tried javascript - but cant get to the field as its within a foreach - not saying its not possible, but I certainly don't know how.

Comment: @Murali HTTPPost from my view to controller

Comment: Isn't it possible to avoid using formData in your case? From my point of view you have problem because of using formData and foreach on the view. If it is possible to change this approach to for (int i = 0;...) and IList parameter in the action, you wouldn't probably need to amend data (which is bad :))

Comment: in long term yes, and that's well on the list to do, but for a proof of concept purpose i'm looking to get it at least stuck together as much as possible without visibly breaking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to amend before it hits your controller, you will need to use Javascript/Jquery to catch the form submit and then amend the value before performing the submit.

You could always change the model in the post method, but bear in mind that the modelstate will be used under the hood if you want to check for any errors or send the model back the view.

If you go this route and change the model in the controller then look at clearing the changed field in the modelstate or clearing the whole modelstate before going back to the view, otherwise you won't see your changes and you need to get the model and modelstate to rebind:

```
model.field1 = newval;
ModelState.Remove("field1");//forces rebind
```

or

```
model.field1 = newval;
ModelState.Clear();//clears modelstate fully
```